# MS-ACCESS is not recognizing a field when applying a Transform to a complex subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

Excuse my english is not really good, so I beg for your comprehension.

1st, I have to say that I'm not really good a Access using :). I use it at work to automate some reports and it is really useful... Since then!! I'm stuck at making this one work since many months, I have to make it work.

I have a database containing some tables and I want to extract and sort foreign trade tables in a precise way to use it in quaterly reports. I've already done most of the tables, but one still hard to implement.

I have to make a Table that shows quaterly variations of 5 last quarters and annual variation of the current quarter, for Exported/ imported goods, sorted by goods.

So at first I tried to make a request that gives for each year and quarter, quaterly variations by products. The sql code looks like this:

```
SELECT Courant.anm, 
       Courant.ctci4, 
       Courant.maxa, 
       Sum(Iif(( ( Courant.valeur - Ancien.valeura ) / Ancien.valeura ) * 100 IS 
               NULL, 
           0, ( 
               ( Courant.valeur - Ancien.valeura ) / Ancien.valeura ) * 100)) AS 
       VTR 
FROM   (SELECT B.annee, 
               B.mois, 
               B.annee & B.mois                                     AS ANM, 
               (SELECT Max(base1.annee & base1.mois) 
                FROM   base1 
                WHERE  base1.annee & base1.mois < B.annee & B.mois) AS MaxA, 
               B.ctci4, 
               Sum(B.valstat)                                       AS Valeur 
        FROM   base1 B 
        WHERE  ( Len(B.ctci4) ) = 1 
               AND ( B.flux = "e" 
                      OR B.flux = "r" ) 
        GROUP  BY B.annee, 
                  B.mois, 
                  B.ctci4) AS Courant 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT base1.annee & base1.mois AS ANM, 
                          base1.ctci4, 
                          Sum(base1.valstat)       AS ValeurA 
                   FROM   base1 
                   WHERE  ( Len(base1.ctci4) ) = 1 
                          AND ( base1.flux = "e" 
                                 OR base1.flux = "r" ) 
                   GROUP  BY base1.annee & base1.mois, 
                             base1.ctci4) AS Ancien 
               ON ( Courant.ctci4 = Ancien.ctci4 ) 
                  AND ( Courant.maxa = Ancien.anm ) 
GROUP  BY Courant.anm, 
          Courant.ctci4, 
          Courant.maxa
```

That part of the request works well. In fact I gives me an Concatenate ID (Courant.ANM),  that I've created to inner join another copy of the same table to be able to show up on the same record the current value and the value of the previous quarter, the product code, The ID of the previous period (concatenate year and quarter) and the field VTR that shows the variation to the previous period in percentage.

To finish i have to make a pivot table by using TRANSFORM. I Have to Put the year & quarter (ANM) in column, the product code (CTCI4) in rows and the value, but when I try, MS ACCESS said that B.annee is not recognized as a valid field name. even If I name differently that field I doesn't work!! Please can someone tell how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code for an Access pivot with the fields you mention(I used a fake table name - test):

```
TRANSFORM Count(test.CTCI4) AS CountOfCTCI4
SELECT test.CTCI4
FROM test
GROUP BY test.CTCI4
PIVOT test.ANM;
```

The error you are getting about B.annee seems to me like it is happening before the data gets to the Transform/Pivot.  Try breaking your query into pieces and testing them - the subqueries first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've just gave the main query sql code to show that it is correct. In fact I make It run perfectly. Slow, but it works. I even tried to save that ouptut in a table and was able to perform my pivot, using that saved table, (using the Transform in the same way you described above). It's only when  when I try to use directly the query in a transform, I shows the error "B.annee is not recognized". But B.annee exists, and works in my query!